# How to move a button in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

width = 800
height = 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Blackjack")
icon = pygame.image.load('jack.jpg')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
over_font = pygame.font.Font('GOODDP__.TTF', 64)
jack = pygame.image.load('rsz_jack.png')
jackX = 295
jackY = 100
running = True

def jack_title():
    screen.blit(jack, (jackX, jackY))

def display_title_text():
    over_text = over_font.render("Blackjack", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (292, 300))

def start_button():
    button = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 255, 0], button)
    button.move(0, 0)
    over_text = over_font.render("START!", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (0, 75))
    clicked = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if clicked[0] == 1:
        print('Clicked left button!')
    elif clicked[1] == 1:
        print('Clicked middle button!')
    elif clicked[-1] == 1:
        print('Clicked right button!')
    else:
        pass


def quit_button():
    button = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [255, 0 ,0], button)

def display_gameover_message():
    over_text = over_font.render("GAME OVER", True, (0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(over_text, (292, 300))

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((150, 173, 252))
    jack_title()
    display_title_text()
    start_button()
    quit_button()
    pygame.display.update()
```

I am trying to move my start_button() to the bottom of the screen but I do not know how to move it as i tried `pygame.Rect.move()` and `pygame.Rect.move_ip()` but they do not seem to move the button. I want to reposition the button so that once I click the button it allows me to exit the title page of my game.

Answer (score 0):

The location of the start button is define by the [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object `button` in the function `start_button`. The 2nd argument defines the top of the button. Just change the 2nd argument, e.g. `height-50` rather than 100:

```py
def start_button():

    # button = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)
    button = pygame.Rect(50, height-50, 100, 50)

    # [...]
```

Another possibility is to set the `.top` of `button` equal to the bottom of the window, after the rectangle is defined:

```py
def start_button():

    button = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50) 
    button.bottom = height 

    # [...]
```

Note, the Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to move and align the rectangle. See [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

---

If you want to move the button in the later in the application, then you have to define `start_button_rect` in global namespace:

```py
start_button_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 100, 100, 50)

def start_button():
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, [0, 255, 0], start_button_rect)

    # [...]
```

Now, you can change `start_button_rect`, for instance by [`move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip):

```py
start_button_rect.move_ip(0, 400)
```

or by setting a virtual attribute:

```py
start_button_rect.bottom = height
```